# Azure Storage Blob with CodeIgnitor

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, azure-blob-storage

I'd have a PHP {codeigniter} application that i want to migrate to  its  storage service from AWS S3 to Blob Storage,The application uploads all media files to S3 bucket and S3 generates a link that is stored to the database in which the media file can be accessed from,I want to do the same with azure Blobs storage.I'm facing technical hindrance as i can't find the right resources {libraries/code samples} achieve this goal.Tried the Azure PHP SKD but it didn't work out.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more details as to what didn't work out. Share any code that you have written and include any errors you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a detailed sample for using Azure Storage PHP SDK. You may refer to: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/samples/BlobSamples.php

To run that sample, you just need to replace the following place with your own value:

```
$connectionString = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<yourAccount>;AccountKey=<yourKey>';
```

---

### Suggestion:

I see that you want to generate an access url and store it in database. I am not familiar with AWS S3, but with Azure Storage you may need to s[et public access level on container or blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-access-to-resources).

Otherwise, you can not access the blob directly. You may need to created a [SAS token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview).